# php - how to remove namespace when calling object from independent class?

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I'm calling an independent class's static function like: `AnimeshPlugin::get_plugin_basename();`

AnimeshPlugin is defined class... I'm using namespace AniPlugin\custom;
and when i call this function within this namespace class, error occured as:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'AniPlugin\custom\AnimeshPlugin'
>   not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\animesh-plugin\includes\config\custom\admin.php
>   on line 25

I don't want to add AniPlugin\custom\ before the class name.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\AnimeshPlugin::get_plugin_basename();
```

Look into [Importing Namespaces in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) and [Global Space](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php)

Comment: The AnimeshPlugin::get_plugin_basename(); is available in non-namespaced common file i want to access it as same i don't want to add namespace in calling... it is independent.

Comment: in simple words it is ""AnimeshPlugin::get_plugin_basename();"" not ""AniPlugin\custom\AnimeshPlugin\AnimeshPlugin::get_plugin_basename();""

Comment: accepting ur answer in 5mins as per limit of 10min wait before acception